# Where to put same code? mixin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a class `Formular` in my `lib`-folder that is `extend` by a module, that is also allocated in my `lib`-folder:

It looks something like this: **formular.rb**

```
class Formular
  extend Userfield
  def self.ueberweisung
    ..................
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => [width,height], :margin => 0 )
    pdf.image image_path, :at  => [w, height], :fit => [width,height]

    create_userfield

    pdf.stroke_line [w + 9.1.mm, h - 60.mm], [w + 14.2.mm, h - 65.mm]
    ..................
```

`create_personenfeld` is defined in **userfield.rb**

```
module Userfield 
  def create_userfield
      pdf.font("Courier", :size => 12) do
        pdf.draw_text "Thanks for your help", :at => [w + 11.mm, h - 13.mm]
        ..........
```

As supposed i become a error because `pdf` is not `defined` in the `def create_userfield`!

```
 undefined local variable or method `pdf' for Formular:Class
```

Now my question is where should i put such a method? So that i dont have to pass each variable to it?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add an class variable called pdf:

```
attr_accessor :pdf
```

It will be shared between all methods of the class and you will be able to call you pdf as @pdf.

Example:

```
> module Animal
>   def say
      @word
>   end
> end
> class Doge
>   include Animal
>   attr_accessor :word
>   def initialize
>     @word = 'such cool feature'
>   end
> end

> dog = Doge.new
> dog.say
=> 'such cool feature'
```